# Identification of missing data

Tags: excel, xls, xlsx

I have three tabs in an Excel sheet. One is a summary of the other two which consist of data to be matched with the first, summary, tab.

Do we have any option to highlight if the data is missing in the first tab?

Answer (score 1):

I think yes. Name the range in your first sheet (say `S1Array` and for example here Refers To $A$1:$C$3 in S1). Then apply (here to $A1:$C3) a Conditional Formatting rule in your summary sheet of:

> =NOT(INDEX(S1Array,ROW(),COLUMN()))

along with the highlighting of your choice:

[image: SO17877454 example]